# Postman Console Output Clickable URL

Tags: postman

How can I output a clickable URL in the Postman Console (native app) from within a test script?

Like the "https://go.pstmn.io/postman-jobs" when you start the Postman Console.

Comment: Can I ask why you would need to do this?

Comment: I would like to do a demo of a sequence of API calls. The last call returns lat/long data which serves as input for Google Maps. I didn't find a way to launch this URL directly.

Answer (score 0):

For the sequence of API calls, you might be using a runner.
So you may store the lat-long values in variable and pass them to the other URL of google maps.

Request 1: You need to store value of lat-long in environment

```
       let resp = pm.response.json();

       pm.environment.set("latitude",resp.lat); 

       pm.environment.set("longitude",resp.longitude);

       postman.setNextRequest("Googlemaps"); // need to pass request name(used in postman) which need to be called
```

Request 2: In runner, for the second request add below line in tests to stop the test:

```
       postman.setNextRequest(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I found a hacky way to do this.

### Step 0. Have your URL

There are plenty of ways using the pre/post script features in Postman to generate this from some API output

### Step 1. Setup a simple API running on localhost launching the browser

For me I did this using express and node, something like

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const open = require('open');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = 1;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/open-url', (req, res) => {
  open(req.body.q);
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Running on http://localhost:1.

### Step 2. Create a GET request in Postman

A simple example

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:1/open-url' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'q=http://google.com'
```